# Select row where ?? equals to x

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have a table that contains a few rows. Each row has a column named "color", with the type of string. I want to get all the rows where the column contains the string "red".

It is set like this:

```
let myTable = Table("myTable")
let id = Expression<Int>("id")
let color = Expression<String>("color")
let taste = Expression<String>("taste")
```

How can I do this?

I tried something like `myTable.filter`, but not sure how to accomplish what I want when it is stored as a string.

EDIT:

It looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: What sort of library are you using with SQLite?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Make title more specific.

Comment: @OOPer https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

Comment: Explain your data model. Are you using a library like SQLite? Do you just have an array of objects? If you're using a third party library to manage an SQLite database, tell us that too. We're not mind-readers.

Comment: You should better include the info into the text of your question. I do not know much about the library, but someone who knows it can help you.

Comment: New edit in post now.